# Why I cannot see the blind value in my RSA-blind code in Python?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am trying to enhance the security level of my RSA Python code by adding blind operation, but it does not work, so I cannot do encryption and decryption because I cannot get the blind value. Then I realized I lost the blind value and tried to fix it, but still, there is no change. I can input data but there is no output. How can I fix this problem? Thank you!

Here the relevant code:

```
import random
import sys

def primeNumber(n, d):
    a = random.randint(2, (n - 2) - 2)
    x = pow(a, int(d), n) 
    if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
        return True

    # square of x
    while d != n - 1:
        x = pow(x, 2, n)
        d *= 2

        if x == 1:
            return False
        elif x == n - 1:
            return True
    
    # if is not prime
    return False

def isPrime(n):#return True if n prime fall back to primeNumber if uncertain
    # 0, 1, -ve numbers not prime
    if n < 2:
        return False

    # low prime numbers
    lowPrimes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]

    # if in lowPrimes
    if n in lowPrimes:
        return True

    # if low primes divide into n
    for prime in lowPrimes:
        if n % prime == 0:
            return False
    
    # find number c  c * 2 ^ r = n - 1
    c = n - 1 # c even bc n not divisible by 2
    while c % 2 == 0:
        c /= 2 # make c odd

    # prove not prime 128 times
    for i in range(128):
        if not primeNumber(n, c):
            return False

    return True

def generateKeys(keysize=1):
    e = d = N = blank = 0

    # get prime nums, p & q
    p_input=input("Enter the prime number p:")
    q_input=input("Enter the prime number q:") 
    
    p=  int( p_input)
    if p > 1:
        for i in range(2, p//2):
            if (p % i) == 0:
                print(p, "is not a prime number")
                sys.exit()
                break
           
    q=  int( q_input)
    if q > 1:
        for i in range(2, q//2):
            if (q % i) == 0:
                print(q, "is not a prime number")
                sys.exit()
                break
    
            
                   
    
    N = p * q # p and q multiplication
    
    totientN = (p - 1) * (q - 1) # totient
    
    
    
    # e is coprime with totientN & 1 < e <= totientN
    
    while True:#e
        e = random.randrange(2 ** (keysize- 1), 2 ** keysize - 1)
        if (CoPrime(e, totientN)):
            break

 
    # d is mod inv of e with respect to totientN, e * d (mod totientN) = 1
    d = modularInv(e, totientN) #d
    
    
    
    return e, d, N,blank

def CoPrime(p, q): #return True if gcd(p, q) is 1 relatively prime
    return gcd(p, q) == 1

def gcd(p, q):# euclidean algorithm to find gcd of p and q
    while q:
        p, q = q, p % q
    return p

def egcd(a, b):
    s = 0; old_s = 1
    t = 1; old_t = 0
    r = b; old_r = a

    while r != 0:
        quotient = old_r // r
        old_r, r = r, old_r - quotient * r
        old_s, s = s, old_s - quotient * s
        old_t, t = t, old_t - quotient * t

    # return gcd, x, y
    return old_r, old_s, old_t

def multiplication(keysize,blank,N,e):
    blindRSA=0
    while True:#create blinder
        blindRSA=random.randrange(2 ** (keysize- 1), 2 ** keysize - 1)
        if(CoPrime(blank, N)):
            break
    return blindRSA

def blindRSAalg(blank,blindRSA,e):
    blinded=0
    blinded=blank*(blindRSA**e)
    return blinded

def blindInv(blinded,N):
    blind=0
    blind=blinded%N
    
    return blind
    
def modularInv(a, b):
    gcd, x, y = egcd(a, b)

    if x < 0:
        x += b

    return x


def encrypt(e, N, msg):
    cipher = ""

    for c in msg:
       # print ("C is that" ,c)
        m = ord(c)  #string to ascii
        print("M is that" ,m) 
        cipher += str(pow(m, e, N)) + " " 
        #print("C is that" ,cipher)
    return cipher

def decrypt(d, N, cipher):
    msg = ""

    parts = cipher.split()
    for part in parts:
        if part:
            c = int(part)
            msg += chr(pow(c, d, N))

    return msg

def main():
    print("Run")
    keysize = 32
    e, d, N,blank= generateKeys(keysize)

    msg = input("Enter the message :")
    blank=int(input("Enter the blank number:"))
    blindRSA= multiplication(keysize,blank,N,e)
    blinded =blindRSAalg(blank,blindRSA,e)
    blind= blindInv(blinded,N)
    enc = encrypt(e, N, msg)
    dec = decrypt(d, N, enc)

    print("Input message:",msg)
    print("e:",e)
    print("d:",d)
    print("blank:",blank)
    print("blinder:",blindRSA)
    print("blinded:",blinded)
    print("blind:",blind)
    print("N:",N)
    print("Encryption message:", enc)
    print("Decryption message:", dec)

main()
```

Comment: Now, delete the question at crypto?

Comment: I deleted the question at crypto, thank you. Also, I'll be glad if you know the answer and help me. @kelalaka

Comment: There is a [gmpy](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy/) libary that can reduce your code greatly. That is a python extension of GNU GMP.  This will help you consantrate only your binding problem. Did you test all of your functions?

Comment: You don't use the blinder value. You lost it. You should keep it, then use it. Python can return multiple values. Use it to save or generate separately then send to the blinder function and unblinder function.

Comment: My all functions are working well which is related to RSA algorithm. Then I wanted to add blind operation and its functions to enhance the security level of RSA, but it does not work, so I am not sure about the functions which are related to the blind operation. @kelalaka

Comment: The `blinder` value doesn't get out from your  `multiplication` function ( not a good naming the `blindRSA` way better ). Just get it out, then use it in `blindInv`

Comment: I did it as you said, but there is still no change. I edited the codes. What should I do to fix it? @kelalaka